# Importing from "export default as" runs all code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a files like this:

**components/carousel.js**

```
import hammerjs from 'hammerjs';
import React from 'react';

export default () => <div>...</div>;
```

**components/layout.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => <div>...</div>;
```

**components/index.js**

```
export { default as Carousel } from './carousel';
export { default as Layout } from './layout';
```

Now in my server side rendered app I import layout like so:

```
import { Layout } from './components';
```

I get an error about `window` not being defined, because it's reading through `components/index.js` and seeing hammerjs dependency inside the Carousel export, which requires window and isn't available on the server.

Why is it reading the code in the Carousel component when I'm only trying to import the Layout component? How do I avoid this happening?

Comment: Because it must import all dependencies of your dependency in order to do the import.

Comment: Is this the case even though I’m not importing Carousel (which contains the hammerjs dependency)?

Comment: Javascript won't just selectively parse specific lines from a file. The entire file gets executed. Which includes the line that imports carousel.

Comment: I actually ran into this same problem recently in production when I was building a PWA. The problem i found was that the index.js file was being bundled in the main.js chunk. Therefore, all components and dependencies would be imported as soon as the main chunk was downloaded. Also importing the index.js file from a component imports all components. This is clearly not very progressive. As a result, I had to import each component individually (which was a pain), and I had to lazy load routes and 3rd party libraries. After having experienced this, I'd ecommend that you decouple your components.

Answer (score -1):

In short - why is it reading the Carousel component?

You are exporting two defaults in your `components/index.js` which is not a supported operation. Export the named components individually or one default objet that holds both.

---

1) From MDN on import/exports - `You can have multiple named exports per module but only one default export.` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

In your components index file you're exporting both as default - export the named variable. Then import the named variable.

2) The HammerJS dependency shouldn't matter. Your react code will be run through some sort of transpiler that will take the node modules and turn them into something the browser can understand.

Comment: I don’t think this is correct. I do not have 2 default exports, I have 2 named exports (renaming the default exports from the relevant files). This is valid JS as far as I’m aware: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Oof you are correct - my apologies, I tried to downvote myself haha. My `HammerJS` comment still stands though - are you running your code through webpack or something?